# How to force quirks mode on chrome ( "BackCompat" property on compatMode )?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently using selenium to run tests on a client's website ( old website that I don't have control and it will NOT be changed by the client).

The problem is that a specific segment of the website only works if I'm using IE11 with document mode 5 (basically it changes rendering to quirks mode). I would not like to use IEDriver + macros , since I would need to rewrite everything for IE and would need to add another program for the macros.

Is there any way to force the load of a page on chrome on quirks mode ? It can be via JS injection, chrome extension, selenium settings, doctype alteration before DOM rendering, etc.

All answers I found would need total control of the website (changing doctype string).

Thanks!

Comment: You can strip the doctype string while the page is loading by using request interception via the raw CDP protocol commands (Selenium should be able to send those), look for examples for `Fetch.getResponseBody`, `Fetch.fulfillRequest` ([here's](https://forum.katalon.com/t/intercepting-request-with-chrome-devtools-protocol/36081) an example for another automation environment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with an intermadiate proxy intercepting all chrome requests. Not the simplest or elegant solution but it works.